# How do I change this if conditional into a switch statement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, switch-statement

I tried to change the following code from an if statement into a switch statement but I get an error saying that I need an integer and not an id object.

here's my switch:

```
-(void) nearestIndexAfterRotationEnded:(int)index {
NSLog(@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]);
statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]];

switch ([colorNames objectAtIndex:])) {
    case 1:
        [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        break;

    case 2:
        [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

and here's my if conditional statement:

```
-(void) nearestIndexAfterRotationEnded:(int)index {
NSLog(@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]);
statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]];


if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:0]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:1]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:2]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:3]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:4]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:5]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_6.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:6]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_7.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:7]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_8.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:8]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_9.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

}

thanks for any help

Comment: What class of object are you putting into colorNames?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm looking to change a button image based on which object in an array is selected. it's a rotation wheel and when the user rotates it the button image should change

Comment: You don't even need a switch statement....why not just use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Btn1_%d.png", index];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change it the code 
 switch ([colorNames objectAtIndex:]))
to 
switch (index)  This will be helpful for you.
```

Comment: You don't know if the colorName objectAtIndex:index is going to match index value.

Comment: @hanumanDev Whenever your colorNames change order inside the array, it's gonna stop working. You should be aware of that.

Comment: Also disagree to this answer. We have just a code snippet, but as it is, index doesn't get included in the decision which image to display.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)nearestIndexAfterRotationEnded:(int)index {
    NSLog(@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]);
    statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]];

    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:i]) {
            [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Btn1_%d.png", i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but why loop? As I see it it is [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Btn1_%d.png", colorNames.count]]

Comment: colorNames.count - it is static variable, we have dynamic image names

Comment: Don't quite get what you mean. The count should be working, I'm guessing here the array doesn't hold more than 9 items. No object in there can be nil so the the looped if statement simply checks the count, essentially. Granted, there might be more than 9 items (which I doubt in this setting). Then instead of using colorNames.count using MAX(9,colorNames.count) would solve this.

Comment: i believe that @hanumanDev knows what he doing. So, index constraints isn't problem of this question.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think he knows so much what he is doing ;) and still, the looping part seems unnecessary since using the count (or count/maximum 9) does the same thing as your loop. But well, he seems happy with the switch index answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change that into a switch statement as it does not fulfil the prerequisites for a switch.

Switch always follows the pattern

```
switch aVar {

case value1:
case value2:
default: 

}
```

You would have to find an alternative algorithm if you insist on using a switch statement.

Comment: the only one who sees that the provided code snippet doesnt take the index variable into account (see my answer) - PS: hallo aus Deutschland :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I couldnt help but answer, although most has already been said.

This is your original if-statement you want to change to switch statement:

```
-(void) nearestIndexAfterRotationEnded:(int)index {
NSLog(@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]);
statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected item is: %@", [colorNames objectAtIndex:index]];


if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:0]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:1]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:2]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:3]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:4]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:5]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_6.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:6]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_7.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:7]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_8.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if ([colorNames objectAtIndex:8]) {
    [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_9.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

Now this is not possible, since you need a variable to switch.

**Now, all the answers dont see, that what you are doing in the if statements has nothing to do with the passed index variable. It never appears in there. (which I think is by mistake)**

Instead, you check from 0-8 if an object exists at index 0-8 in your colorNames array.
If any of the if statements fail, it means that all the following will fail, too because

```
if ([colorNames objectAtIndex: i])
```

returns NIL, it means that this is the end of the array!

So checking if ([colorNames objectAtIndex: 0-8]) is essentially pointless or at least calls for simplification. This whole if-statement thing can be condensed to one line of code:

```
        [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Btn1_%d.png", colorNames.count]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That is, if the colorNames doesnt hold MORE than 9 objects. If it holds more than 9 objects and you still want to check only if the first 9 exist, this one line of code does the trick:

```
[redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Btn1_%d.png", MAX(9,colorNames.count)]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Remember, in the whole if-thing the passed in index variable isnt taken into account.

If that was by mistake and you want to return the name of the object in your array at index, also no multiple ifs would be needed:

```
if ([colorNames objectAtIndex: index])
 [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Btn1_%d.png", index+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So I think, you either need to clarify your question (because more cannot be done with your code snippet) or improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use int in a switch. So, you have to convert `[colorNames objectAtIndex:1]` to an integer. I don't know what are the objects at color, whether they are an NSNumber or NSString, but I am going to assume the latest.

You have to switch like this:

```
switch ([[colorNames objectAtIndex:index] intValue]))
```

The intValue message tells the NSString to return an integer representation of it. That way you can switch.

Comment: Well, that is right but does not appear to solve the problem.

Comment: @HermannKlecker which problem it does not solve? He is getting an error that says "that I need an integer and not an id object." That solves the error. Why downvote?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason he wants to address anc compare object at index 1 in the first branch and object at index 2 in the second. This cannot be achieved with a switch, for sure not with your suggestion. I guess that NeverBe's suggestion with the for loop is closest to solving the problem. humanDev might want to add a break statment in the if within the for loop depending on what he really wants to achieve (which he did not yet tell us).

Answer (score -2):

Can you run this code?

```
switch ([colorNames objectAtIndex:])) {
```

should throw an error. You are not passing a value to objectAtIndex!

It should be

```
switch ([colorNames objectAtIndex:index])) {
```

Comment: if I try:  switch ([colorNames objectAtIndex:index]) {
        case 0:
            [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            break;
            
        case 1:
            [redButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn1_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
    }      I get a "statement requires expression of integer type ('id' invalid)"

Comment: you cant switch on an object from an NSArray, a switch statement requires an integer value, so this will never work